# PostgreSQL Select value row depending on another value row

Tags: postgresql

How to select only the value of the column ***phase*** that corresponds to the value of the column ***type***?, that way I want to show only the ***TAXI_SMALL*** values if the value of ***type*** is ***small_airport***, or ***TAXI_LARGE*** If the value of ***type*** is ***large_airport*** as in a sample of my table:

| ident | type | aircraft | phase | co2_lto_kg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| LFPG | large_airport | AC300 | APPROACH | 2033.64 |
| LFPG | large_airport | AC300 | CLIMB OUT | 3279.83 |
| LFPG | large_airport | AC300 | TAKE OFF | 1281.1932 |
| LFPG | large_airport | AC300 | TAXI_LARGE | 3675.672 |
| LFPG | large_airport | AC300 | TAXI_MEDIUM | 2261.952 |
| LFPG | large_airport | AC300 | TAXI_SMALL | 1413.72 |

The desired result:

| ident | type | aircraft | phase | co2_lto_kg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| LFPG | large_airport | AC300 | APPROACH | 2033.64 |
| LFPG | large_airport | AC300 | CLIMB OUT | 3279.83 |
| LFPG | large_airport | AC300 | TAKE OFF | 1281.1932 |
| LFPG | large_airport | AC300 | TAXI_LARGE | 3675.672 |

This is the code I've so far and I know that the `CASE` instance is not at all right...

```
select 
ident, type, aircraft, phase,
avg(co2_by_phase_lto) as co2_lto_kg,
case(
    WHEN t.type ilike 'large'||'%' THEN phase('TAXI_LARGE')
)
from aviation.emissionsco2 as t
where t.aircraft ilike '%'||'300' and
t.rep_airp ilike '%'||'lfpg'
group by ident,phase
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NOT LIKE` to include all the non taxi related data -- check that the `phase` doesn't begin with `TAXI_`. Then add for each size a comparison that couples the airport size to the taxi route with `OR`.

```
SELECT *
       FROM aviation.emissionsco2
       WHERE phase NOT LIKE 'TAXI$_%' ESCAPE '$'
              OR (phase,
                  type) IN (('TAXI_LARGE',
                             'large_airport'),
                            ('TAXI_MEDIUM',
                             'medium_airport'),
                            ('TAXI_SMALL',
                             'small_airport'));
```